# Authorization in Swift

Tags: macos, sockets, proxy, swift

```
var authRef: AuthorizationRef
var authFlags: AuthorizationFlags = AuthorizationCreate(rights:nil, environment:kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags:kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, authorization:&authRef)
```

[image]

**Error**

```
/AppDelegate.swift:26:89: 'kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment' is unavailable: use 'nil' instead of this imported macro
```

**Error**

```
/AppDelegate.swift:26:45: Cannot convert the expression's type '$T6' to type 'AuthorizationFlags'
```

**How to convert this objective-c code into swift?**

```
static AuthorizationRef authRef;
static AuthorizationFlags authFlags;
authFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults
| kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights
| kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed
| kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize;
OSStatus authErr = AuthorizationCreate(nil, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, authFlags,&authRef);
```

**Xcode Project file**
https://github.com/jaywcjlove/Proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of second error is: `AuthorizationCreate` returns  `OSStatus`. But you assign the result to `authFlags` which is a different type.